# composer get installation error for phpseclib

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, phpseclib

I am trying to install phpseclib in Laravel for RSA. I have tried following command.

```
composer require phpseclib/phpseclib
```

But I do get following error.

**Using version ^2.0 for phpseclib/phpseclib
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.**

Problem 1

- The requested package symfony/translation (locked at v4.4.7, required as 4.3.8) is satisfiable by symfony/translation[v4.4.7] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Problem 2

- Conclusion: remove symfony/cache-contracts v2.0.1
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache-contracts v2.0.1
- don't install symfony/contracts v1.1.6|don't install symfony/cache-contracts v2.0.1
- don't install symfony/contracts v1.1.7|don't install symfony/cache-contracts v2.0.1
- don't install symfony/contracts v1.1.8|don't install symfony/cache-contracts v2.0.1
- Installation request for symfony/cache-contracts (locked at v2.0.1) -> satisfiable by symfony/cache-contracts[v2.0.1].
- Installation request for symfony/translation 4.3.8 -> satisfiable by symfony/translation[v4.3.8].
- Conclusion: don't install symfony/translation-contracts v2.0.1|install symfony/contracts v1.1.6|install symfony/contracts v1.1.7|install symfony/contracts v1.1.8
- Conclusion: remove symfony/translation-contracts v2.0.1|install symfony/contracts v1.1.6|install symfony/contracts v1.1.7|install symfony/contracts v1.1.8
- symfony/translation v4.3.8 requires symfony/translation-contracts ^1.1.6 -> satisfiable by symfony/contracts[v1.1.6, v1.1.7, v1.1.8], symfony/translation-contracts[v1.1.6, v1.1.7, v1.1.9].
- Can only install one of: symfony/translation-contracts[v1.1.6, v2.0.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/translation-contracts[v1.1.7, v2.0.1].
- Can only install one of: symfony/translation-contracts[v1.1.9, v2.0.1].
- Installation request for symfony/translation-contracts (locked at v2.0.1) -> satisfiable by symfony/translation-contracts[v2.0.1].

**Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.**

Given below is the content of composer.json file.

```
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"version": "v1.2.0",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "berkayk/onesignal-laravel": "^1.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "~2.3",
    "egulias/email-validator": "^2.1",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "infyomlabs/coreui-templates": "6.0.x-dev",
    "infyomlabs/laravel-generator": "6.0.x-dev",
    "intervention/image": "^2.5",
    "laminas/laminas-diactoros": "^2.2",
    "laravel/framework": "^6.0",
    "laravel/passport": "^7.5",
    "laravel/socialite": "^4.3",
    "laravel/telescope": "^2.1",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^6.0",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
    "phpseclib/phpseclib": "^2.0",
    "pusher/pusher-php-server": "~4.0",
    "spatie/laravel-analytics": "^3.9",
    "spatie/laravel-permission": "^3.2",
    "symfony/translation": "4.3.8",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~9.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.6",
    "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "files": ["app/helpers.php"],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
}
```

I have tried for couple of hours to search solution on google and stack overflow but didn't get any success.

Comment: please add the contents of your composer.json to your question.

Comment: @segFault i have updated post.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure the given error message is related to `phpseclib/phpseclib`? That package does not use any Symfony dependencies. And, according to the dependency list of `laravel/passport`, that library is already installed.

I would assume that you have installed another package in the meantime by adding it to `composer.json` manually. What happens if you call `composer install` - does it inform you that the installation is not possible, or that the lock file is out of sync?

You could resolve this by removing `symfony/translation` from your `composer.json`, run `composer update`, and try to reinstall this package afterwards. Because somehow `symfony/translation-contracts` got installed in v2.0.1 (which is only compatible with Symfony 4.4 or later), while your configuration explicitly tries to load `symfony/translation` from Symfony 4.3